# Not showing the Form in html

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

**This is my model**

```
class showroom(models.Model):
 serialno=models.IntegerField(db_index=True,primary_key=True)
 carname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
 carmodel=models.CharField(max_length=50)
 price=models.IntegerField()
 rating=models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(5)])
```

**This is my forms.py**

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
 class Meta:
    model = showroom
    fields =("__all__")
```

**views.py**

```
class carform(CreateView):
 model = showroom
 form_class=RegisterForm
 template_name = "carbrand/carregister.html"
 context_object_name='registerform'
```

**html page**

```
{% block content %}
    {{registerform}}
{% endblock content %}
```

**It's just showing a blank screen. I have imported all the necessary classes and views. It will make this too long for you so i removed it.can anyone please tell me if anything wrong in my view/form.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the form is not determined by the `context_object_name`. In fact in a `CreateView`, the `context_object_name` does not change anything since no object is passed.

A `FormView` (and its descendants), always pass the form that is constructed as `form` to the context. You thus should render this with:

```
{% block content %}
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'some-view-name' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
{% endblock content %}
```